# Use For-Loop as a code in Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink

let's say I build a simulink model and wanted to execute it under For loop, how can I export the model to run in Matlab code?

```
for(a=1;a<=7;a++)
   {
     input1=10;
     input2=12;
     input3= input1/input2;
     output = (a*input3)-input1-input2;
    }
```

The input1, input2 and input3 are come from the Simulink model that I built. The 'a' variable is come from the for loop code, the model will run until a<=7. How can I do it in Matlab?

Comment: See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html

Comment: That isn't valid syntax for a `for` loop for a start, so start with some basic syntax learning and work up to using `run` to run your Simulink model - using `a` as the end time in your model should be straightforward since Simulink is happy to use workspace variables as an end time in the model's settings.

Comment: See [Run Simulations Programmatically](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/using-the-sim-command.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use "To Workspace" blocks inside the Simulink diagram in order to store the results in the workspace.

Change the for loop to something like:

```
for(a=1;a<=7;a++)
   {
     load('system_name.mdl'); %loads the simulink diagram
     sim('system_name.mdl'); %runs the simulink diagram
     %input1 comes from "To Workspace"
     %input2 comes from "To Workspace"
     input3= input1/input2;
     output = (a*input3)-input1-input2;
    }
```